# Creating a matrix of summary output

Tags: r

How can I insert summary outputs from multiple regression analyses in a matrix type variable in R statistics package?

Here is my script, which runs the regression and collect intercepts and co-eff in a variable:

```
for (i in 2:(ncol(data.base)))     {
  Test <- lm(data.base[,i] ~ log(database$var.1))
      results <- rbind(results, c(Test$coefficients))
}
```

I would like to do is to import `summary(lm-test)` for each regression in to a matrix type variable. I assume the matrix type variable is what I need.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: This type of programming question is better fitted to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Yuck! Some nasty variable naming there, in my opinion.

I see `data.base` has outcomes, and you don't want the first column but each is a separate outcome. You also have `database` which is a data.frame with a variable `var.1`. Run each regression, store them in a matrix format.

This is a start:

```
fits <- apply(data.base[, -1], 2, function(y) lm(y ~ log(database$var.1))
summ <- lapply(fits, summary)
summ <- lapply(fits, coef)
Reduce(cbind, summ)
```